# I want to change content in checkout page but can not find it

Tags: onepage-checkout, template, ce-1.9.0.1

After reaching the shopping cart and clicking checkout we get the page: checkout/onepage

it is the regular step by step checkout and it is called onepage

here is my question:

In step 1 of this page there is some info like : register and save time!

I want to have some different lines of text that better cover what we want to tell our customers.

In what file should i do that? i have searched in app/design/frontend/.../templates/html/ but i can't find a file that has this info...

And...

can i put that also in the translation files after that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick and easy way to do this would be to turn inline translation on and edit the text.

> NOTICE: *Don't do this on a live site!*

1. Go to System > Configuration
2. In the configuration under Advanced go to Developer > Translate Inline
   [image]
3. Set "Enabled for frontend" to "Yes"
4. Save the configuration
5. Make sure to disable cache
6. Go to the frontend and get to the point in checkout where you would like to change the text
7. Hover over the text you would like to change and click on the book icon next to the text
8. Change the custom field to whatever text you would like it to say.
   [image]
9. Click on "Submit"

Refresh the page and you should see the new text.  Make sure to disable inline translation by turning "Enabled for frontend" back to "No"

**Caution**
Enabling inline translation on the frontend will allow customers to see and make changes to the inline translation functionality.

Also be aware that this will change the translation in the data set so if you migrate the code to another server without the data or change the original translation text in the phtml where it states:

> <?php echo $this->__('Register and save time!') ?>

the translation will not stick.

**More permanent solution**
Would be to either rewrite the phtml template in

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
>   or
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml

*Or in the rwd theme in 1.9.0.1*

This approach would give you greater flexibility to make changes to the formatting.

You could always add a more permanent translation in a translation csv file.